# Selenium testing with DoubleClick AD on page

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently writing a selenium test case for a page which has doubleClick ad integrated in header and footer.

Selenium works perfectly fine until it comes to test this page, and test breaks with following issue.

```
Exception class=[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking Window.getComputedStyle() with arguments [Text, String]
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:669)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:601)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:507)
```

I wonder any one has gone through issue.
Here is my stack
WebDrive : Firefox
HtmlUnit   2.12
Selenium-htmlunit-driver-2.33.0

I think css getting pulled by doubleclick on runtime causing the issue.
Any help in this regard will be helpful.

Comment: If you had provided html code of part(that you want to automate) of your test page and your Selenium code to automate test case, it would have been helpful to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium 3.x double click not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356348/selenium-3-x-double-click-not-working)